# Scraping Trading Economics website graph data with Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, graph

New to Python, to Selenium and to HTML as well and with very little programming experience but trying hard... I've managed to scrape tables from tradingeconomics.com without problems but when trying to scrape graph datapoints I got completely stuck. Have been studying elements/network in developer tool for days now and getting basically nowhere (see te-snip here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UhGQ.jpg). I've looked through everything I've managed to find in stackoverflow as questions/answers relating to this but with no luck. I understand embedded graph comes from JavaScript but can't find any values (except some forecast values) and url for graph gives just a png figure. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me if my problem is unsolvable (e.g. graph data is just beoynd reach without API token) and if not, point me to right direction. This is where I got with start of the script (I know, it's basically nothing...):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = "https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/composite-pmi"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url) 
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

name = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h1").text
#content = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,("//div[@id='historical']"))
graph = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "chart-figure")

#just to check what comes out
print(name)
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "chart-figure"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))

driver.quit()
```

Searhed stackoverflow, studied HTML and accessed tags, but didn't find values in scripts or elsewhere so uphill became too steep.